# Uploading multiple images in sync with a data model class

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, model, image-uploading

I want to upload multiple images to amazon and then upadate the image links to my server. I want them to be uploaded in a data model class so that if I switch to another controller I can easily get back the status of the images. So what should be the design of my data model class. I want the status of each and every image that has been lined up in a queue for upload.

Comment: Upload images in for loop.. in loop you can dispatch_async the whole task inside the for loop. each time the loop runs . it will dispatch a task to a thread. So you can concurrently upload to S3 and on S3 success , just a API call to serve with image URL as parameter .

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @coreDeviOS Lets say, I've 5 images and I start uploading them and I moved to a new controller. And in the new controller, I want the status of every image uploaded or still uploading with the progress(I get the progress while uploading to Amazon). So how should I do it?

Comment: Make NSNotificationDefault that will post a notification in Application. You can post the notification from S3 server progress block.